# How to block align text in SwiftUI Text View?

Tags: swift, swiftui

There is left, center and middle aligned text.
Yet no block alignment like in other Word Processors.

How can one align text in a view using block format?

[image: XCode Attributes]

[image: Example from Word]

Comment: Seems like it has to be done through UIKit UILabel

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you put text in a label, you can justify the text contained in this way:

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified
```

Comment: import UIKit
let intro = "text..."
intro.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

gives an error.. .how is it done?